# How can you set two named ranges as a chart data source?

Tags: vba

I have two named ranges as detailed below:

```
Set JRange = sht.Range(sht.Cells(StartRow, 10), sht.Cells(LastRow, 10))
Set DRange = sht.Range(sht.Cells(StartRow, 4), sht.Cells(LastRow, 4))
```

I want to use both of them as sources for my specified chart macro. This is what I have:

```
Set Chart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=300, Width:=325.9842519685, Top:=10, Height:=277.5118110236)

With Chart
    .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(DRange) And (JRange), PlotBy:=xlColumns
    .Chart.ChartType = xlLine
    .Chart.ChartStyle = 2
    .Height = 277.5118110236
    .Width = 325.9842519685
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a new Series' `Values` and `XValues` separately:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim JRange As Range, DRange As Range, chtObj, cht As Chart
    Dim StartRow, LastRow, sht

    StartRow = 3 'for testing
    LastRow = 15 'for testing
    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    Set JRange = sht.Range(sht.Cells(StartRow, 10), sht.Cells(LastRow, 10))
    Set DRange = sht.Range(sht.Cells(StartRow, 4), sht.Cells(LastRow, 4))


    Set chtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=300, _
               Width:=325.9842519685, Top:=10, Height:=277.5118110236)

    With chtObj.Chart
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .ChartStyle = 2
        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Values = JRange
            .XValues = DRange
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```